# Are workflows also triggered through the API?

Tags: api, workflow, php

Does anyone know if workflows are triggered by calls from the API? I have a workflow that is triggered by updating an opportunity. It then sends an outbound message to an external page that updates that same opportunity through the API and it seems to be continuously running. After reviewing the code thoroughly, I have come to the conclusion that this has to be the case, but can anyone confirm? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Workflow rules always execute for single and mass edit UI actions, and for normal API calls. The Import Wizard can disable workflow rule actions, and administrative mass edits (e.g. Replace Picklist Value) will not trigger workflow rules. Also, some other actions, such as transferring record ownership, also will not trigger workflow rules. See the page [Workflow Rule Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_rules_considerations.htm&language=en_US) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

Workflows do get fired when data is inserted or edited from the API .

One exceptional case we have observed it does not is when data is synced through outlook using salesforce for outlook.

Also if the setting is everytime the record is created or edited in workflow and if criteria is satisfied each time record is inserted or edited workflow rules execute while **if we have third criteria to subsequently evaluate when edited you wont find it running everytime**