# Records created via API not triggering workflow/process

Tags: trigger, api, workflow

I have Tasks that are automatically created using an app Sidekick, which logs emails sent from gmail as activities.

To my knowledge, workflows can usually be trigger by records created via API. (source: [Are workflows also triggered through the API?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19100/are-workflows-also-triggered-through-the-api))

But my process is not picking them up (unless I edit them in the UI) Any thoughts or workarounds?

Comment: what do debug logs shows up?Better to check logs to see whats happening at backend when tasks getting created?

Comment: Is it possibly related to the user that the Sidekick app is running as?

Comment: Hey Daniel. It's running as me, an admin, so I don't think that would be the issue

Comment: Hey Mohith, I checked the logs and I see three events that are triggered. not sure what I should be looking for though